# MySQL - Query performance issues - taking 25+ seconds

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to figure out why this query is taking so long.  Before, it was executing in approx 150ms to 200ms but now it's taking 25 seconds or longer.  And this was between last night and this mroning.  The only thing that's changed is add data to tables.

Based on the explain output below and also the sql I've provided, is there anything that stands out that would explain why the query takes so long now?

update: Per the comment from halfer, I changed the order by to `ORDER BY pins.pin_id` and it brought the execution time to 172ms.

Also, I wanted to mention that the table pins has 20 million records, boards as 339,000 records, users has 352738 records.

```
+----+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table         | type            | possible_keys                                | key     | key_len | ref                            | rows | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | <derived11>   | system          | NULL                                         | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                           |    1 |                          |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | pins          | index           | user_id,user_id_2,latitude,longitude,lat_lon | vip     | 1       | NULL                           |  646 | Using where              |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | users         | eq_ref          | PRIMARY                                      | PRIMARY | 8       | skoovy_prd.pins.user_id        |    1 |                          |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | boards        | eq_ref          | PRIMARY                                      | PRIMARY | 8       | skoovy_prd.pins.board_id       |    1 |                          |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | via           | eq_ref          | PRIMARY                                      | PRIMARY | 8       | skoovy_prd.pins.via            |    1 |                          |
| 12 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | users         | unique_subquery | PRIMARY                                      | PRIMARY | 8       | func                           |    1 | Using where              |
| 11 | DERIVED            | NULL          | NULL            | NULL                                         | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                           | NULL | No tables used           |
| 10 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | users_avatars | ref             | pin_id                                       | pin_id  | 14      | skoovy_prd.users.user_id,const |    1 | Using where              |
|  9 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | users_avatars | ref             | pin_id                                       | pin_id  | 14      | skoovy_prd.users.user_id,const |    1 | Using where              |
|  8 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | users_avatars | ref             | pin_id                                       | pin_id  | 14      | skoovy_prd.users.user_id,const |    1 | Using where              |
|  7 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pins_images   | ref             | pin_id                                       | pin_id  | 14      | skoovy_prd.pins.pin_id,const   |    1 | Using where              |
|  6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pins_images   | ref             | pin_id                                       | pin_id  | 14      | skoovy_prd.pins.pin_id,const   |    1 | Using where              |
|  5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pins_images   | ref             | pin_id                                       | pin_id  | 14      | skoovy_prd.pins.pin_id,const   |    1 | Using where              |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pins_images   | ref             | pin_id                                       | pin_id  | 14      | skoovy_prd.pins.pin_id,const   |    1 | Using where              |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pins_reports  | index           | user_id                                      | user_id | 115     | NULL                           |    1 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pins_likes    | ref             | pin_id,pin_id_2,user_id                      | pin_id  | 16      | skoovy_prd.pins.pin_id,const   |    1 | Using index              |
+----+--------------------+---------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

The SQL:

```
SELECT 
    `pins`.`pin_id` AS `pin_pin_id`,
    `pins`.`check_unique_id` AS `pin_check_unique_id`,
    `pins`.`category_id` AS `pin_category_id`,
    `pins`.`board_id` AS `pin_board_id`,
    `pins`.`user_id` AS `pin_user_id`,
    `pins`.`date_added` AS `pin_date_added`,
    `pins`.`date_modified` AS `pin_date_modified`,
    `pins`.`likes` AS `pin_likes`,
    `pins`.`comments` AS `pin_comments`,
    `pins`.`repins` AS `pin_repins`,
    `pins`.`description` AS `pin_description`,
    `pins`.`title` AS `pin_title`,
    `pins`.`image` AS `pin_image`,
    `pins`.`price` AS `pin_price`,
    `pins`.`price_currency_code` AS `pin_price_currency_code`,
    `pins`.`price_type` AS `pin_price_type`,
    `pins`.`price_from` AS `pin_price_from`,
    `pins`.`price_to` AS `pin_price_to`,
    `pins`.`event_type` AS `pin_event_type`,
    `pins`.`event_start` AS `pin_event_start`,
    `pins`.`event_end` AS `pin_event_end`,
    `pins`.`from` AS `pin_from`,
    `pins`.`from_md5` AS `pin_from_md5`,
    `pins`.`from_repin` AS `pin_from_repin`,
    `pins`.`is_video` AS `pin_is_video`,
    `pins`.`views` AS `pin_views`,
    `pins`.`latest_comments` AS `pin_latest_comments`,
    `pins`.`source_id` AS `pin_source_id`,
    `pins`.`via` AS `pin_via`,
    `pins`.`repin_from` AS `pin_repin_from`,
    `pins`.`public` AS `pin_public`,
    `pins`.`ub_id` AS `pin_ub_id`,
    `pins`.`total_views` AS `pin_total_views`,
    `pins`.`delete_request` AS `pin_delete_request`,
    `pins`.`pinmarklet` AS `pin_pinmarklet`,
    `pins`.`vip` AS `pin_vip`,
    `pins`.`store` AS `pin_store`,
    `pins`.`width` AS `pin_width`,
    `pins`.`height` AS `pin_height`,
    `pins`.`ext` AS `pin_ext`,
    `pins`.`location` AS `pin_location`,
    `pins`.`latitude` AS `pin_latitude`,
    `pins`.`longitude` AS `pin_longitude`,
    IF(pins.price_type != ''
            AND (pins.price_type = 'CUSTOM_RANGE'
            AND pins.price_from <> 0.00
            AND pins.price_to <> 0.00
            AND pins.price_from < pins.price_to)
            OR (pins.price_from <> 0.00),
        1,
        0) AS `pin_show_pricing`,
    IF(pins.price_type = 'CUSTOM_RANGE',
        CONCAT('$',
                pins.price_from,
                '-',
                '$',
                pins.price_to),
        CONCAT('$', pins.price_from)) AS `pin_price_text`,
    IF((pins.event_start IS NOT NULL
            || pins.event_end IS NOT NULL)
            && (pins.event_start != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
            || pins.event_end != '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
            && (event_type = 'multiple'
            || event_type = 'single'),
        1,
        0) AS `pin_show_event`,
    IF(pins.event_type = 'multiple',
        CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(pins.event_start, '%Y-%m-%d'),
                ' - ',
                DATE_FORMAT(pins.event_end, '%Y-%m-%d')),
        DATE_FORMAT(pins.event_start, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS `pin_event_text`,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(like_id)
        FROM
            `pins_likes`
        WHERE
            (pin_id = pins.pin_id)
                AND (user_id = 57610)
        LIMIT 1) AS `pin_is_liked`,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(pr_id)
        FROM
            `pins_reports`
        WHERE
            (pin_id = pins.pin_id) AND (checked = 0)
                AND (user_id = '57610'
                OR user_ip = '44021cb8')
        LIMIT 1) AS `pin_is_reported`,
    (SELECT 
            CONCAT_WS('|||',
                        image,
                        width,
                        height,
                        original,
                        mime)
        FROM
            `pins_images`
        WHERE
            (pin_id = pins.pin_id) AND (size = '_A')
        LIMIT 1) AS `pin_thumb_a`,
    (SELECT 
            CONCAT_WS('|||',
                        image,
                        width,
                        height,
                        original,
                        mime)
        FROM
            `pins_images`
        WHERE
            (pin_id = pins.pin_id) AND (size = '_B')
        LIMIT 1) AS `pin_thumb_b`,
    (SELECT 
            CONCAT_WS('|||',
                        image,
                        width,
                        height,
                        original,
                        mime)
        FROM
            `pins_images`
        WHERE
            (pin_id = pins.pin_id) AND (size = '_C')
        LIMIT 1) AS `pin_thumb_c`,
    (SELECT 
            CONCAT_WS('|||',
                        image,
                        width,
                        height,
                        original,
                        mime)
        FROM
            `pins_images`
        WHERE
            (pin_id = pins.pin_id) AND (size = '_D')
        LIMIT 1) AS `pin_thumb_d`,
    `users`.`user_id` AS `user_user_id`,
    `users`.`source` AS `user_source`,
    `users`.`source_uuid` AS `user_source_uuid`,
    `users`.`is_business` AS `user_is_business`,
    `users`.`username` AS `user_username`,
    `users`.`password` AS `user_password`,
    `users`.`email` AS `user_email`,
    `users`.`new_email` AS `user_new_email`,
    `users`.`new_email_key` AS `user_new_email_key`,
    `users`.`business_name` AS `user_business_name`,
    `users`.`business_phone` AS `user_business_phone`,
    `users`.`firstname` AS `user_firstname`,
    `users`.`lastname` AS `user_lastname`,
    `users`.`groups` AS `user_groups`,
    `users`.`status` AS `user_status`,
    `users`.`last_action_datetime` AS `user_last_action_datetime`,
    `users`.`last_login` AS `user_last_login`,
    `users`.`ip_address` AS `user_ip_address`,
    `users`.`following` AS `user_following`,
    `users`.`followers` AS `user_followers`,
    `users`.`avatar` AS `user_avatar`,
    `users`.`facebook_id` AS `user_facebook_id`,
    `users`.`twitter_id` AS `user_twitter_id`,
    `users`.`twitter_username` AS `user_twitter_username`,
    `users`.`is_admin` AS `user_is_admin`,
    `users`.`is_developer` AS `user_is_developer`,
    `users`.`gender` AS `user_gender`,
    `users`.`location` AS `user_location`,
    `users`.`latitude` AS `user_latitude`,
    `users`.`longitude` AS `user_longitude`,
    `users`.`website` AS `user_website`,
    `users`.`date_added` AS `user_date_added`,
    `users`.`new_password` AS `user_new_password`,
    `users`.`new_password_key` AS `user_new_password_key`,
    `users`.`facebook_session` AS `user_facebook_session`,
    `users`.`boards` AS `user_boards`,
    `users`.`pins` AS `user_pins`,
    `users`.`likes` AS `user_likes`,
    `users`.`latest_pins` AS `user_latest_pins`,
    `users`.`description` AS `user_description`,
    `users`.`facebook_connect` AS `user_facebook_connect`,
    `users`.`facebook_timeline` AS `user_facebook_timeline`,
    `users`.`twitter_connect` AS `user_twitter_connect`,
    `users`.`dont_search_index` AS `user_dont_search_index`,
    `users`.`delete_account` AS `user_delete_account`,
    `users`.`delete_account_date` AS `user_delete_account_date`,
    `users`.`groups_pin_email` AS `user_groups_pin_email`,
    `users`.`comments_email` AS `user_comments_email`,
    `users`.`likes_email` AS `user_likes_email`,
    `users`.`repins_email` AS `user_repins_email`,
    `users`.`follows_email` AS `user_follows_email`,
    `users`.`email_interval` AS `user_email_interval`,
    `users`.`digest_email` AS `user_digest_email`,
    `users`.`news_email` AS `user_news_email`,
    `users`.`first_login` AS `user_first_login`,
    `users`.`store` AS `user_store`,
    `users`.`width` AS `user_width`,
    `users`.`height` AS `user_height`,
    `users`.`instagram_connect` AS `user_instagram_connect`,
    `users`.`instagram_profile_id` AS `user_instagram_profile_id`,
    `users`.`instagram_token` AS `user_instagram_token`,
    `users`.`enable_follow` AS `user_enable_follow`,
    `users`.`public` AS `user_public`,
    users.username AS `user_fullname`,
    (SELECT 
            CONCAT_WS('|||',
                        image,
                        width,
                        height,
                        original,
                        mime)
        FROM
            `users_avatars`
        WHERE
            (user_id = users.user_id)
                AND (size = '_A')
        LIMIT 1) AS `user_avatar_a`,
    (SELECT 
            CONCAT_WS('|||',
                        image,
                        width,
                        height,
                        original,
                        mime)
        FROM
            `users_avatars`
        WHERE
            (user_id = users.user_id)
                AND (size = '_B')
        LIMIT 1) AS `user_avatar_b`,
    (SELECT 
            CONCAT_WS('|||',
                        image,
                        width,
                        height,
                        original,
                        mime)
        FROM
            `users_avatars`
        WHERE
            (user_id = users.user_id)
                AND (size = '_C')
        LIMIT 1) AS `user_avatar_c`,
    `boards`.`board_id` AS `board_board_id`,
    `boards`.`category_id` AS `board_category_id`,
    `boards`.`user_id` AS `board_user_id`,
    `boards`.`image` AS `board_image`,
    `boards`.`date_added` AS `board_date_added`,
    `boards`.`date_modified` AS `board_date_modified`,
    `boards`.`sort_order` AS `board_sort_order`,
    `boards`.`title` AS `board_title`,
    `boards`.`description` AS `board_description`,
    `boards`.`followers` AS `board_followers`,
    `boards`.`pins` AS `board_pins`,
    `boards`.`public` AS `board_public`,
    `boards`.`latest_pins` AS `board_latest_pins`,
    `boards`.`cover` AS `board_cover`,
    `boards`.`delete_request` AS `board_delete_request`,
    `boards`.`views` AS `board_views`,
    `boards`.`total_views` AS `board_total_views`,
    `via`.`user_id` AS `via_user_id`,
    `via`.`source` AS `via_source`,
    `via`.`source_uuid` AS `via_source_uuid`,
    `via`.`is_business` AS `via_is_business`,
    `via`.`username` AS `via_username`,
    `via`.`password` AS `via_password`,
    `via`.`email` AS `via_email`,
    `via`.`new_email` AS `via_new_email`,
    `via`.`new_email_key` AS `via_new_email_key`,
    `via`.`business_name` AS `via_business_name`,
    `via`.`business_phone` AS `via_business_phone`,
    `via`.`firstname` AS `via_firstname`,
    `via`.`lastname` AS `via_lastname`,
    `via`.`groups` AS `via_groups`,
    `via`.`status` AS `via_status`,
    `via`.`last_action_datetime` AS `via_last_action_datetime`,
    `via`.`last_login` AS `via_last_login`,
    `via`.`ip_address` AS `via_ip_address`,
    `via`.`following` AS `via_following`,
    `via`.`followers` AS `via_followers`,
    `via`.`avatar` AS `via_avatar`,
    `via`.`facebook_id` AS `via_facebook_id`,
    `via`.`twitter_id` AS `via_twitter_id`,
    `via`.`twitter_username` AS `via_twitter_username`,
    `via`.`is_admin` AS `via_is_admin`,
    `via`.`is_developer` AS `via_is_developer`,
    `via`.`gender` AS `via_gender`,
    `via`.`location` AS `via_location`,
    `via`.`latitude` AS `via_latitude`,
    `via`.`longitude` AS `via_longitude`,
    `via`.`website` AS `via_website`,
    `via`.`date_added` AS `via_date_added`,
    `via`.`new_password` AS `via_new_password`,
    `via`.`new_password_key` AS `via_new_password_key`,
    `via`.`facebook_session` AS `via_facebook_session`,
    `via`.`boards` AS `via_boards`,
    `via`.`pins` AS `via_pins`,
    `via`.`likes` AS `via_likes`,
    `via`.`latest_pins` AS `via_latest_pins`,
    `via`.`description` AS `via_description`,
    `via`.`facebook_connect` AS `via_facebook_connect`,
    `via`.`facebook_timeline` AS `via_facebook_timeline`,
    `via`.`twitter_connect` AS `via_twitter_connect`,
    `via`.`dont_search_index` AS `via_dont_search_index`,
    `via`.`delete_account` AS `via_delete_account`,
    `via`.`delete_account_date` AS `via_delete_account_date`,
    `via`.`groups_pin_email` AS `via_groups_pin_email`,
    `via`.`comments_email` AS `via_comments_email`,
    `via`.`likes_email` AS `via_likes_email`,
    `via`.`repins_email` AS `via_repins_email`,
    `via`.`follows_email` AS `via_follows_email`,
    `via`.`email_interval` AS `via_email_interval`,
    `via`.`digest_email` AS `via_digest_email`,
    `via`.`news_email` AS `via_news_email`,
    `via`.`first_login` AS `via_first_login`,
    `via`.`store` AS `via_store`,
    `via`.`width` AS `via_width`,
    `via`.`height` AS `via_height`,
    `via`.`instagram_connect` AS `via_instagram_connect`,
    `via`.`instagram_profile_id` AS `via_instagram_profile_id`,
    `via`.`instagram_token` AS `via_instagram_token`,
    `via`.`enable_follow` AS `via_enable_follow`,
    `via`.`public` AS `via_public`,
    via.username AS `via_fullname`,
    `row` . *,
    @curRow:=@curRow + 1 AS `pin_pin_row`
FROM
    `pins`
        LEFT JOIN
    `users` ON pins.user_id = users.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
    `boards` ON pins.board_id = boards.board_id
        LEFT JOIN
    `users` AS `via` ON pins.via = via.user_id
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT @curRow:=- 1) AS `row`
WHERE
    (pins.user_id = 57610
        OR IF(pins.user_id = 57610, 1, pins.public) = 1)
        AND (pins.latitude <= 40.78666477795
        AND pins.latitude >= 40.64193322205
        AND pins.longitude <= - 73.910342436525
        AND pins.longitude >= - 74.101288363475)
        AND (pins.user_id = 57610
        OR pins.user_id IN (SELECT 
            user_id
        FROM
            users
        WHERE
            public = 1))
ORDER BY pins.vip DESC , pins.pin_id DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: This query looks like that huge ship that appears in the beginning of the movie "spaceballs" :-)

Comment: I'm no expert, but selecting a million columns probably won't give you great performance.

Comment: This is a debugging problem - try removing pieces until the performance returns. Keep a copy of the real query, and remove a variety of clauses to see what is most responsible for the slow-down. Left joins are sometimes a cause, and ordering can be expensive as well.

Comment: Does it consistently take 25 seconds or did that just happen the first time?  Maybe it was cached before and had to be re-compiled.

Comment: When I change `ORDER BY pins.vip DESC , pins.pin_id DESC` to just `ORDER BY pins.pin_id` it now takes 172ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two analysts review the sql as well as the tables that are used.  The results where that the sql, along with all indexes, were perfectly fine.  Two tables have almost 300 million records in them.  the main (pins) table has now 28 million records.

So, my solution was to implement [sphinx search](http://www.sphinxsearch.com).  I'm on a dedicated server for the database, so being able to install and tweak was a snap.  Once I set up sphinx, created my initial indexes, and then set up a scheduled diff index & merge process, I've been able to get results  in 100ms and even 60ms in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

you can tried to change this condition:

```
AND (pins.user_id = 57610
OR pins.user_id IN (SELECT 
    user_id
FROM
    users
WHERE
    public = 1))
```

By:

```
AND (pins.user_id = 57610
OR users.public = 1))
```